# How to pass login callback to form error in Meteorite with Mesosphere?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I am using Mesosphere form package for my own custom login page. Heres the login form:

```
Mesosphere({
    name: "loginForm",
    method: "login",
    fields: {

        usernameEmail: {
            required: true,
            format: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,25}$/i,
            message: "only alphanumeric usernames",
            transform:["trim"]
        },

        password: {
            required: true,
            message: "6-25 characters please",
            rules:{
               maxLength:25,
               minLength:6
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Once I validate the object, I want to make sure that this this user login information is valid, if not pass back the information to be rendered as an error.

```
Meteor.methods({
login: function (rawFormData) {
    var validationObject = Mesosphere.loginForm.validate(rawFormData);
    console.log("logging in...");
    if (!validationObject.errors) {
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(validationObject.formData.usernameOrEmail, 
                                    validationObject.formData.password,
                                    function (err) {
                                        if (err) {
                                            //user doesnt exit
                                            console.log("user doesnt exist");
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            //user logged in...
                                            console.log("logged in");
                                        }
                                    }
                                 );

    }
    else {
        console.log("errors:" + JSON.stringify(validationObject.errors));
    }
},
```

I want to specify a username-error or password-error to show up.

```
<template name="login">
log in please
<form name="loginForm">

    <p><input type="text" name="usernameOrEmail" placeholder="username or email"/></p>
    <span id="usernameOrEmail-error"></span>

    <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/></p>
    <span id="password-error"></span>

    <input type="submit" value="Login"> or <a href="{{pathFor 'signup'}}">Sign Up</a>
</form>
```

clarification:

I want to be able to implement an additional validation step on either the client or the server. On the client, I'd like to be able to check if the given login credentials are valid (on the client). If I am creating a new user, I'd like to be able to check that a user with that username doesnt already exist (on the server).

clarification 2:

I understand you can invoke a function or method with the "method" element (https://github.com/copleykj/Mesosphere#basics-elements) but how can I return a success or error and how is the message handled?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default error functionality with onFailure callback. It goes on the same level of fields inside the object. https://github.com/copleykj/Mesosphere/blob/master/README.md#error-management

Comment: So onSuccess I would call a server method to check if that user exists -- then how to i initiate a failure?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. onFailure will be risen if the form validation fails else it will raise onSuccess

Comment: You have to create a custom rule. Get my code as example: https://github.com/gabrielhpugliese/meteor_supercalendar/blob/master/lib/forms.js

Comment: Ah. That example make much more sense. However, how can you register a rule that depends on a combination of the inputs? For example, I dont want to check just the username or just the password. I want to know if the combination is a valid user login credential.

Comment: On a side note, I'm not sure this is secure because validation supposedly happens on both client and server, meaning that the password is sent raw to the server... right?

Comment: Yeah that's something to worry about. I don't know much about how Meteor does it, but maybe it's better you ask it on meteor-talk@googlegroups